# Are helper classes mandatory for all Magento extensions?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Many extensions (including the one's I've written) include a helper class that just extend the abstract base class without adding any functionality. The helper usually looks like this:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

The extended class is therefore just used for things that the abstract class provides, especially for translations. On the other hand, all Block and Controller classes in Magento inherit the `__()` method for translations - and in an extension I'm currently developing I don't have the need to call the helper class even once.

Can I just delete the helper class and remove it from `config.xml`? I've tried it and the extension seems to work fine without, but due to Magento's complexity I'm always a bit worried that there are implications I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're creating a module from scratch, helper classes aren't strictly necessary. I usually skip creating one until it's needed.

**However**, if any XML file uses the `module` attribute to specify a translation module, that attribute needs to resolve to a valid helper.  For example, in this core file

```
<!-- File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml -->
<tabs>
    <catalog translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog</label>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
    </catalog>
</tabs>
```

There's `module="catalog"`.  By specifying this attribute, the Magento system code that translates the label will look something like this

```
Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Label');
```

So, removing the helper from the catalog module would break parts of Magento.

(The single part class alias `catalog` is automatically converted to `Mage::helper('catalog/data')` by Magento system code)

This "helper to group translations" feature is used in **many** of Magento's XML files, not just `system.xml` (layout, widgets, etc.).  Additionally, there are some systems in Magento that will infer and/or require the existence of a helper module for translations (Access Control, external API system,etc. )

Long Story Short: If you're creating a module from scratch, feel free to leave the helper out until you start getting errors that Magento can't instantiate a helper.  Never remove an existing helper from a module, and if you want to make sure you're 100% compatible with assumptions other people might make, always include a `Data.php` helper class.

Answer (score 4):

Magento's Helper classes contain utility methods that will allow you to perform common tasks on objects and variables. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento#6

Assuming that the Helper file is empty with no custom methods eg.

```
<?php 
class MagePal_SomeModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Then some of things that may still be  affected are:

- system.xml - blank screen for your module in admin -> system -> config
- $this->__('') - error in your .phtml template (for internationalization/translation)

So if your helper is empty, without a system config section and no translation then it 'maybe' ok to delete.